# Can an outlet connected to another outlet using pigtail and the connected to afci outlet

Tags: electrical, afci

I already have an outlet circuit connected to an AFCI outlet, just before the electrical box. Is it up to code to add another regular outlet by pig-tailing just before the AFCI outlet and connecting to the AFCI outlet? I'm in Ontario, Canada.

Comment: Does the new outlet need to be AFCI protected?

Comment: Yes, it must be afci protected.

Comment: Since the second outlet must also be AFCI protected simply connect your new duplex to the "output screws" of the AFCI. This will now protect both outlets with the same AFCI unit.

Comment: Keep in mind, AFCI is not the same thing as GFCI. AFCI mainly detects problems *with the wiring in the walls*.   Whereas GFCI detects problems with appliances.  It's perfectly fine to ignore the "Load" terminals on a GFCI and simply put a GFCI receptacle at each outlet. However an AFCI is basically pointless if you do that.   In the US you must use AFCI at the start of the circuit (the breaker) unless the wiring to the first outlet is in metal conduit or 2" of concrete.

Comment: Yes the AFCI is the first outlet. There is metal conduit wiring and from AFCI to the panel. What I m trying is to add another outlet directly to AFCI by pig-tailing the new and wires from existing circuit to AFCI. Will this cause any issues?